# print one page in text file using python

Tags: python, file

I am quiet new to python, and I want to extract one page from a text file. Each page starts with a unique line and ends with '//'. And I want to find a way to return a certain page knowing the unique line associated with it. Do you know what tools can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `split` the file by `"//"` and then `split` by `"\n"` to obtain the first line, then creating a dictionary associating a line with a page.

```
header_to_page = {}
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
    pages = content.split("//")
    for page in pages:
        lines = page.split("\n")
        header_to_page[lines[0]] = "".join(lines[1:])

print header_to_page["example line"]
```

Comment: could you explain the line header_to_page[lines[0]] = lines[1:]?

Comment: @smvpfm `lines[0]` is the first item in the list (the first line, a.k.a the header). `lines[1:]` are the items from index 1 to the end (a.k.a the rest of the list, a.k.a the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the textfile and use split for the "//"

```
file = open(“testfile.txt”, “r”) 
contents = file.read() 
pages = contents.split("//")
```

pages is now a list and you can indicate which index you want to get

```
print(pages[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try splitting the text in to a list:

```
import pickle

text= "hello this is a unique line. and it will end with // this should be 
the other line and it also ends with // a third line just for good mesure//"
pickle.dump(text, open("text.txt","wb"))

page = pickle.load(open("text.txt","rb")).split("//")[0]

print(page)
```

and then just index the page you want in this line:

```
 page = pickle.load(open("text.txt","rb")).split("//")[0]
```